# Crawling wss3 site from SP2010 standard using STS3 url

Tags: search, wss-3.0, crawl-external-content

I'm bringing up a SP 2010 standard instance and want to configure it to crawl the old **WSS3** site collection until the migration is done. I understand that the proper method is to use the **STS3** urls rather than `http`. If I configure `http://oldsite.example.com` as a source, it works correctly. If I configure `sts3://oldsite.example.com` I get the message:

> The start address sts3://oldsite.example.com/ cannot be added when
>    crawling the entire web application. Either select to crawl only the
>    SharePoint site, or provide a hostname only start address to crawl.

which is probably the worst error description I have ever read.

What should my search urls look like?

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that it doesn't recognise the URI as a web application hostname. You can change the crawl settings to "Only crawl the Site Collection of each start address" and see if that works, but I don't think it will find all your site collections and is probably not what you want. I suggest you use the http: protocol, which it obviously is correctly accepting as the hostname for your WSS web application.

Answer (score 1):

If you select SharePoint Site as **ContentSource**, the following protocols are supported:

- `http`
- `https`
- `sps3`
- `sps3s`

Checked in the `SharePointContentSource` class in the `Microsoft.Office.Server` Assembly

Answer (score 0):

I never had luck with sts3 early on, with 2010 we just use the http URL of our site for the crawls and have never had issues.